# Nitration of N-phenylbenzamide

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why during nitration of *N*-phenylbenzamide the $\ce{NO2}$ group is directed at para-position of the ring attached to the nitrogen atom?
Okay, I understand that this is due to the *para* directing effect of the $\ce{>NH}$ group. But carbonyl $\ce{>C=O}$ group has a *meta* directing effect, then why is $\ce{NO2}$ not directed to the *meta*-position of the benzene ring attached to carbonyl group?

> In the following reaction
>
> [image: N-phenylbenzamide]
>
> (1) $\ce{NO2}$ group at *meta* position w.r.t. Ring 2
> (2) $\ce{NO2}$ group at *para* position w.r.t. Ring 1
> (3) $\ce{NO2}$ group at *para* position w.r.t. Ring 2
> (4) $\ce{NO2}$ group at *meta* position w.r.t. Ring 1

Comment: The carbonyl attached to ring 2 is meta directing but deactivating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be looking at $\ce{-NH-CO\bond{-}}$ as two different functional groups i.e. as $\ce{-NH-}$ and $\ce{-CO-}$.

Since as in $\ce{-(NH-CO)\bond{-}}$: $\ce{N}$'s lone pair are actually in resonance with the carbonyl group.

The left handed phenyl ring is more activated than the right handed phenyl ring. Hence the electrophile would preferentially attack on the left handed phenyl ring.

The amide group is too weak base to be protonated by the acid and therefore it *does not* direct the electrophile to *meta* position.

*Ortho* position is hindered due to steric hindrance of the another phenyl ring.

And therefore

> the attack takes place at para position of the left handed phenyl ring

so answer should be option B.

Comment: @andselisk : Could you suggest me some perfect and to the point editing tips

Comment: Feel free to visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on MathJax and Markdown formatting. Also there is a glorified [MathJax reference from Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).